# Why declaring int in method which pointing to Node is working?

Tags: java, recursion, int, binary-search-tree, nodes

I don't understand why declaring 'int' in this method return actual value instead of crash. Is the existence of node counted as 1 (true), and then the combined value of all of "trues" is assigned to int(rDepth or lDepth)?

That is a method of a class in BST.

```
public static int getHeight(Node root){

    if(root==null) {return -1;}

    int rDepth=getHeight(root.right);

    int lDepth=getHeight(root.left);

       return Math.max(rDepth, lDepth)+1;

 }
```

I expected that declaring int and then assigning to it a method which pointing to another object Node will not work at all.

Comment: Please tag your post with the programming language this is written in.

Comment: Where do you think it would "crash"? This is an example of recursion. The method calls itself with increasingly "smaller" subtrees. That the trees get smaller is important, otherwise you might get an infinite recursion (which would indeed crash because it runs out of memory).

Comment: What you are assigning to `rDepth` is not the method itself, but the result of calling the method (with `root.right` as a parameter). That result is an `int` (because that is what the method returns -- it says so in the method signature), so you can assign it to this variable (which is also an `int`).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I can't though understand how the method iterates that int every time it's called, or how it's calculates the number of nodes. It's calling itself, as recursion methods do, but I still don't see the way how the method returns every time it's called some integer value or accumulates it.

Comment: It returns -1 for an empty tree, otherwise `max(depthLeft, depthRight) + 1`. That covers all the cases.